# How to give title for gvisTable in shiny R

Tags: r, googlevis

I am newbie to shiny R and googleVis. I have a method called explore(...) which creates a googleVis chart (either Bar Chart, Pie, etc.) on a separate window depending on the datatype of the variable passed as parameter. It also checks if the user has checked the option of Visualize (checkBox on ui). If it is true, it renders the plot along with a `gVisTable` that holds central tendency and dispersion values. I was able to do this by using `gVisMerge()`.  But if Visualize checkBox is not checked, it only displays `gVisTable` on a separate page. In the latter case I need to give a title to `gVisTable`.

This is what happens on button click. A method named `explore()` is called to generate plot.

```
observeEvent(input$exploreButton, {
      print(input$variableInput)
      options <- list()
      options$variableName <- input$variableInput
      options$visualize <- input$visualizeCheckBox
      options$centralTendency <- input$centralTendencyCheckBox
      options$dispersion <- input$measureDispersionCheckBox
      explore(dataset[, input$variableInput], options)
    })
```

And this is a piece of code from explore method that merges the plot and the table. Or simply displays the gvisTable.

```
informationTable <- gvisTable(as.data.frame.matrix(valuesTable), options=list(height=300, width=200))
    if(options$visualize)
    {
      barChart <- getSimpleBarChart(table(x), paste("Bar Chart for ", options$variableName), "bottom", 1500, 600)
      plot(gvisMerge(barChart, informationTable, horizontal=FALSE))
    }
    else {
      plot(informationTable)
    }
```

Here `getSimpleBarChart(...)` is another method written to generate BarChart i.e.

```
getSimpleBarChart <- function(data, title, legend_location='bottom', width=400, height=400) {
  options <- list(title=title, legend=legend_location, tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}", bar="{groupWidth:'90%'}", width=width, height=height)
  g <- gvisBarChart(as.data.frame(data), options=options)
  g
}
```

Is there any way to give title to `gVisTable` like we do in rest of the googleVis charts? Please help...

Comment: Post some code. Code that runs stand alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by first fetching the header of the gvis table as

```
myGvisTable$html$header
```

It is html therefore, heading can be appended to it easily using the paste() method as

```
informationTable$html$header <- paste("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"\n  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\ ......", "<h2>Your title of table</h2>", "</head>\n<body>\n")
```